# Получить 3 записи

Tags: php

Делаю сайт.Там есть новости, где будут записи от людей на которых я подписан. Как получить только 3 записи от одного пользователя sql
Id•authorid•text

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Id, authorid, text
FROM news
WHERE authorid = [ID пользователя]
LIMIT 3;
```

запрос выбирает только 3 записи из таблицы news, где authorid совпадает с заданным идентиф. пользователя.

Comment: Мне нужно до
Не для одного а для нескольких пользователей